# Is it permissible for a husband to press his wife's feet when her feet are in pain?

Tags: halal-haram, husband-wife, physical-contact

Is it permissible for a husband to press his wife's feet when in pain? Does the wife become a sinner in front of Allah?

My feet sometimes hurt very much, and it gets unbearable.  At these times my husband presses my feet, as there is no one else to do so. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: By "pressing" you mean some kind of massage?

Comment: what make you think this is wrong ?

Answer (score 6):

First of all, the default in Islam is that anything that is not forbidden is allowed.

I am scratching my head on this one. I am a little alarmed that you are panicking about being a sinner because your **husband** touches you. I am frankly perplexed by the question.

Rest assured, there is nothing for you to repent from.

And second, please keep in mind that God is just and fair! I don't know who gave the first experience of Islam but if he or she left you in such a state of worry over the touch of your husband, he or she has done a very negligent job.

Please always keep in mind that God is not a monster. I wish you less pain in your feet (I personally recommend a hot feet bath with a pinch of salt in it. It works for me, but ask your doctor, it depends on the origin of the pain).